# Why do some of my SQL queries work in a VBA script and some don't?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to query an MDB file from an excel VBA script. I know I'm connecting okay because I can get some queries to successfully return results.

Consider 2 queries - fairly simple and similar:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION from MS where CATALOG='3RV1915-6AB'
```

and

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION from MS where MANUFACTURER='100-2SIEMENS'
```

Both queries refer to the *same record* in the MDB table and work fine in Access. The second query also works from Excel VBA code, but the first throws this error:

> [image: Err.Number = -2147467259]

Both `CATALOG` and `MANUFACTURER` columns are `Short Text` fields (though the lengths are different: 60 and 24 respectively). All other MDB Field settings are identical.

I've run out of ideas of how to debug this behavior. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try enclosing CATALOG in [ ]: `[CATALOG]`.

Answer (score 0):

So - apparently I've discovered that "CATALOG" is a key word being used as a field name...

SO - it needs to be "[CATALOG]" to force the interpretation to be the field name.  That solves my problem.

Comment: [Access reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/reserved-words-access-custom-web-app)